# How to stop weight paint from going through the mesh

Tags: particles, weight-painting

When I weight paint the paint goes through the mesh and as I'm also trying to work with particles  it spawns particles (in this case sprinkles) under the mesh and not on top.

[image: icing in weight paint mode showing sprinkles on the underside instead of the top.]

Comment: if your object has no thickness (or if the thickness is created by a Solidify modifier), you'll see the weight on both faces. As for the particles, maybe invert your normals and see if they flip side

Comment: There should be a dedicated doughnuts.stackexchange.com this tutorial appears on here so often.